# ggplot2: move (reposition) the legend so as not to block the graph box

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, legend, legend-properties

[image]

How can I shift the legend by several points (the width of the graph box line) to the left and bottom?

Task: I want to make the background of the legend semi-transparent, but so it doesn't overlap the graph box.

(red border - for better visualization of the problem)

Use the code:

```
image + theme(
    panel.background     = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
    panel.border         = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black", size = 2),
    panel.grid.major     = element_line(color = "#00000040", linetype = 3),

    axis.text            = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title           = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x         = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10)),
    axis.title.y         = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)),

    legend.key           = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    legend.background    = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff80", color = "red", size = 1),
    legend.justification = c(1, 1),
    legend.position      = c(1, 1),
    legend.title         = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),

    plot.title           = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the legend box to align with the outside edge of the plot border, you need to adjust the `legend.box.margin` so that the top edge has the same value as the width of the line defined in `legend.background`.

There was no sample data, so I created some:

```r
library(ggplot2)

x  <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(x = c(x, x), y = c(-cos(x), sin(x)), 
                 group = rep(c("data1", "data2"), each = 100))

image <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = group)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black"))

image + theme(
    panel.background     = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
    panel.border         = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black", size = 2),
    panel.grid.major     = element_line(color = "#00000040", linetype = 3),

    axis.text            = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title           = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x         = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10)),
    axis.title.y         = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)),

    legend.key           = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
    legend.background    = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff80", color = "red", size = 1),
    legend.justification = c(1, 1),
    legend.position      = c(1, 1),
    legend.title         = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
    legend.box.margin    = margin(1, 0, 0, 0),

    plot.title           = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

found it!

```
legend.box.margin    = margin(t = 2, r = 2),
```